# Struts2 Interceptor overflow exception

Tags: authentication, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

I am working on a Login module for a Web Application using Struts2 + Spring + Hibernate, and I want to force the users to Login if they want to navigate trough the site.

I have an LoginInterceptor

```
public class LoginInterceptor implements Interceptor {

public LoginInterceptor() {
}

public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("LoginInterceptor destroy() is called...");
}

public void init() {
    System.out.println("LoginInterceptor init() is called...");
}

public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {

    final ActionContext context = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    //Code

    try {

        Users userObj = (Users) session.getAttribute("userObj");

        if (userObj == null) {
            System.out.println("if from LoginInterceptor");
            return "noLogin";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginInterceptor.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "message", e);
    }

    //Invoke action
    String result = actionInvocation.invoke();

    return result;
}
}
```

My struts.xml

```
 <interceptors>

        <interceptor name="myLocale" class="com.deveto.struts.interceptors.LocaleInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor name="login" class="com.deveto.struts.interceptors.LoginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor name="access" class="com.deveto.struts.interceptors.AccessInterceptor"/>

        <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="myLocale"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="login"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="profiling"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>

    <global-results>
        <result name="noLogin" type="redirectAction">show-login</result>
        <result name="noAccess" type="redirectAction">access-required</result>
    </global-results>

    <action
        name="show-login"
        class="com.deveto.struts.actions.UsersAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">tiles.login</result>
    </action>
```

But when I run the project, I have an Overflow exception, in Stack trace I have nothing, but Mozilla tells me that:

```
      The page isn't redirecting properly  

      Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

and

```
  System.out.println("if from LoginInterceptor");
```

is repeated several times. I don't understand why, but I have more Interceptors, and other works good besides of this.

Comment: How is your `noLogin` result defined?

I suspect it redirects to some login page which again gets intercepted by your `LoginInterceptor` which then redirects... you get the idea.

Comment: I provided the code in the second box, scroll down please the second box and you'll get it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the scroll bars :/ Please see below for my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your `LoginInterceptor` returns its `noLogin` result it redirects and this gets again intercepted by `LoginInterceptor` which turns it into an endless redirect loop.

So you have to exclude your `show-login` from being intercepted by your `LoginInterceptor`, e.g.

Define two interceptor stacks, and set the one **with LoginInterceptor** as default:

```
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
  ... same as in your question ...
</interceptor-stack>

<interceptor-stack name="noLoginStack">
  ... same as in your question but *without* the LoginInterceptor ...
</interceptor-stack>

<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
```

And then for the `show-login` action only, use the **noLoginStack**:

```
<action name="show-login"
    ... >
    <interceptor-ref name="noLoginStack"/>
    ...
</action>
```

Comment: Ok, I've made this, but I have the same result, even if I put the action without any interceptor stack, still the same error

Comment: I just checked it locally with your exact LoginInterceptor, a minimal struts.xml (with the interceptor stacks I suggested above) and two actions: "secret" and "show-login" (which each just result in a HTML simple page) --- if I try to access http://myhost/myapp/secret I redirects once to http://myhost/myapp/show-login.action and then stops.

Are you sure that none of your other interceptors/code is doing something?

Comment: I have made a new app, and have tested it, the same success result, but in my old app is resulting an error. Very strange, I'll need to comment all the source code, and try to test each action in part. Thanks for tips

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Spring Security to do that ?
It's very simple to configure and it works perfectly with Struts2.
Just start from there : http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html or there : http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/07/07/5-minute-guide-to-spring-security/